# how to do anti left join when the left dataframe is aggregated in pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to do anti left join and flatten the table. in the most efficient way possible because the right table is massive.
so the first table is: like 1000-10,000 rows

[image]

and second massive table: (billions of rows)

[image]

the desired outcome is:

[image]

kind of left anti-join, but not exactly.

I tried to join the worker table with the first table, and then anti left join, and it's working. But duplicating the list of the entire category for each employee sounds inefficient and creates a huge duplication of data.

Comment: can you tell me how you want to your join work, i cant relate your desired table to anti-left join.

Comment: I want to subtract from each category the items if they are in table number 2, so that each employee in table 2 will only have rows of items that are in their category in table 1 but not in their personal items in table 2.

Comment: So I assume the second row of your desired table (Danni - B - 20) is a mistake because I can see (B - 20) in the first table. am I right?

Comment: yes, you are right. Oops! I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If one side of your join is small (like your first table) you can use Broadcast function which has a huge impact on your performance. you can read more information about it in :
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-broadcast-variables/ or pyspark documentation.

The below code can do what you want:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a_df.show()
b_df.show()
b_df.join(F.broadcast(a_df), ['category', 'item'], 'left_anti').show()

+--------+----+
|category|item|
+--------+----+
|       A| 123|
|       A| 456|
|       B|  19|
|       B|  20|
|       B|  66|
|       C|  38|
+--------+----+

+------+--------+----+
|worker|category|item|
+------+--------+----+
|   jon|       B|  19|
|   jon|       B|  20|
|   jon|       B|  45|
| danni|       B|  18|
| danni|       B|  19|
| danni|       B|  80|
| danni|       B|  94|
|    al|       A| 123|
|   ben|       C| 100|
|   ben|       C|  50|
+------+--------+----+

+--------+----+------+
|category|item|worker|
+--------+----+------+
|       B|  45|   jon|
|       B|  18| danni|
|       B|  80| danni|
|       B|  94| danni|
|       C| 100|   ben|
|       C|  50|   ben|
+--------+----+------+
```

Comment: It's close, but upside down. If it's arranged like this, I need the right-anti join. Here we got the opposite list to what I need. It is still very effective, maybe there is another step from here that I am missing that will allow to reach the desired result.

Comment: i think 'left' join is what you need.